# Row Over Partition with Case SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, row-number

The `new_commsstream` column below calculates if the previous row's `date`, partitioned by `persondid` and ordered by a few other columns including the `date` in a subquery, is greater than 90 days and returns a 1 if it is and a 0 otherwise:

```
create view Motability_Dataset_Staging_cmp as 
  select 
    mdsc.PersonID,
    mdsc.AddressID,
    mdsc.Email,
    mdsc.Reportdate_month,
    mdsc.Channel,
    mdsc.CommsMedium,
    mdsc.Campaign_Name,
    mdsc.Category,
    mdsc.MRM_Campaign_code,
    mdsc.Action_id,
    mdsc.NumSents,
    mdsc.ReportDate,
    isnull(cmp.ppersonid,mdsc.PersonID) as Prev_PersonID,
    isnull(cmp.paddressid,mdsc.AddressID) as Prev_AddressID,
    isnull(cmp.pmrmcampaigncode,mdsc.MRM_Campaign_code) as Prev_MRMCampaignCode,
    isnull(cmp.pactionid,mdsc.Action_id) as Prev_ActionID,
    isnull(cmp.preportdate,mdsc.ReportDate) as Prev_ReportDate,
    isnull(cmp.commsdaysinterval,0) as Prev_CommsDays,
    isnull(cmp.newcommsstream,0) as New_CommsStream

  from Motability_Dataset_Staging as mdsc
    left join
      (select 
        cmp.row +1 as row,pcmp.row as prow,
        cmp.personid as personid,pcmp.personid as ppersonid,
        cmp.addressid as addressid,pcmp.addressid as paddressid,
        cmp.MRM_Campaign_code as mrmcampaigncode,pcmp.MRM_Campaign_code as pmrmcampaigncode,
        cmp.Action_id as actionid,pcmp.Action_id as pactionid,
        cmp.reportdate as reportdate,pcmp.reportdate as preportdate,
        datediff(day,cmp.ReportDate,pcmp.ReportDate) as commsdaysinterval,
        case when datediff(day,cmp.ReportDate,pcmp.ReportDate) <-90 then 1 else 0 end as newcommsstream
      from
        (select row_number() over(partition by personid order by personid,addressid,reportdate,mrm_campaign_code,action_id)-1 as row,personid,addressid,MRM_Campaign_code,action_id,reportdate from Motability_Dataset_Staging) cmp
        inner join (select row_number() over(partition by personid order by personid,addressid,reportdate,mrm_campaign_code,action_id) as row,personid,addressid,MRM_Campaign_code,action_id,reportdate from Motability_Dataset_Staging) pcmp on cmp.row = pcmp.row and cmp.personid=pcmp.personid
        ) cmp
    on mdsc.PersonID = cmp.personid and mdsc.AddressID = cmp.addressid and mdsc.MRM_Campaign_code=cmp.mrmcampaigncode
```

I'm struggling to then partition by person id and `new_commsstream` so every time there's a 1 within the same `personid` it adds a new row number otherwise returns a 1:

```
personid    new_commsstream row
1       0       1
1       0       1
1       0       1
1       1       2
1       0       2
2       0       1
3       0       1
4       0       1
5       0       1
5       1       2
5       1       3
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea how to accomplish the 90 day part of this as well? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it helps but you do not need to SELECT data for ROW_NUMBER() twice.
You can just place it into a [SQL Server CTE exression](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-select-previous-and-next-rows-with-current-row-in-tsql.aspx) as follows
Then you can refer to it twice

```
;with cmp as (
    select 
        row_number() over(partition by personid order by addressid,reportdate,mrm_campaign_code,action_id) as row,
        personid,
        addressid,
        MRM_Campaign_code,
        action_id,
        reportdate 
    from Motability_Dataset_Staging
), cmp2 as (
    select
        cmp2.*, -- previous values
        cmp.*   -- 
    from cmp
    left join cmp as cmp2 -- previous
        cmp.row = cmp2.row + 1 
)
select 
mdsc.PersonID,
mdsc.AddressID,
mdsc.Email,
mdsc.Reportdate_month,
mdsc.Channel,
mdsc.CommsMedium,
mdsc.Campaign_Name,
mdsc.Category,
mdsc.MRM_Campaign_code,
mdsc.Action_id,
mdsc.NumSents,
mdsc.ReportDate,
isnull(cmp.ppersonid,mdsc.PersonID) as Prev_PersonID,
isnull(cmp.paddressid,mdsc.AddressID) as Prev_AddressID,
isnull(cmp.pmrmcampaigncode,mdsc.MRM_Campaign_code) as Prev_MRMCampaignCode,
isnull(cmp.pactionid,mdsc.Action_id) as Prev_ActionID,
isnull(cmp.preportdate,mdsc.ReportDate) as Prev_ReportDate,
isnull(cmp.commsdaysinterval,0) as Prev_CommsDays,
isnull(cmp.newcommsstream,0) as New_CommsStream
from Motability_Dataset_Staging as mdsc
inner join cmp on ......
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I try to run the CTE part, I get the error that row is specified multiple times for cmp2?

Comment: Think it has something to do with:

`select
cmp2.*, -- previous values
cmp.*`

I've tried to explicitly state all the columns but it still get an error.

Comment: You can change the column names from previous table as you did in your example like adding some identifer at the end or at the beginning

Comment: Please can you explain by giving an example? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of 

select
    cmp2.*, -- previous values
    cmp.*   -- 
from cmp
left join cmp as cmp2 -- previous
    cmp.row = cmp2.row + 1 

you can use


select
    cmp2.personid pre_personid, -- previous values
 cmp2.addressid pre_addressid, -- previous values
 cmp2.MRM_Campaign_code pre_MRM_Campaign_code, --
 ...
    cmp.*   -- 
from cmp
left join cmp as cmp2 -- previous
    cmp.row = cmp2.row + 1

Comment: Getting an error on `cmp.row = cmp2.row + 1`. This is the code:
`;with cmp as 
(
select 
row_number() over(partition by personid order by addressid,reportdate,mrm_campaign_code,action_id) as row,
personid,
addressid,
MRM_Campaign_code,
action_id,
reportdate 
from Motability_Dataset_Staging_addr
)
, cmp2 as (
select
cmp2.row as prev_row,
cmp2.personid as prev_personid,
cmp2.addressid as prev_addressid,
cmp2.MRM_Campaign_code as prev_MRM_Campaign_code,
cmp2.action_id as prev_actionid,
cmp2.reportdate as prev_reportdate, 
cmp.*
from cmp
left join cmp as cmp2 -- previous
cmp.row = cmp2.row + 1 
)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply btw.

Comment: On LEFT JOIN there must be a joining condition defined by ON.   Please replace with following "    left join cmp as cmp2 on cmp.row = cmp2.row + 1  "